# Flutter Widget Rebuild Stats not showing the details of the widgets

Tags: flutter

I am trying to track widget rebuilds for my flutter application. I tried the flutter performance tab and checked the "track widget rebuild", like the following Image. Now it's just showing me that some widgets are rebuilding but don't show any information about any widget i.e. which widget is being rebuilt.

How do I solve this problem??

[image]

Comment: mine is not even showing the tree,, any fixes ?